# 2 queries in same sql

Tags: c#, sql

I have a dataset where I have some daily observations. I want to group them by date and later take the average of the daily Sum per day (in SQL).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sk1Jf.png]

The SQL used to group by day looks like this and works.

```
"SELECT Date, Sum(Margin) FROM [OpenPositions] GROUP BY Date"
```

I have tried the following code to do the intended query in one SQL.

```
    "SELECT Datepart(week, Date), 
            Avg(avgmargin) 
      FROM (SELECT Datepart(year, Date) Year, 
                   Datepart(week, Date) Week, 
                   Sum(Margin) sum 
              FROM [OpenPositions] 
  GROUP BY Datepart(year, Date), 
           Datepart(week, Date)"
```

But this does not work (not showing any data). Can anyone find the mistake in my sql query, and how to come around it?

All help appreciated.

Comment: SQL is a language. Which DBMS are you using? Read tag description for SQL.

Comment: You are trying to selecte DatePart(week, Date) from the sub query but ther is no column named Date in that sub query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select Datepart(week, Date), Avg(avgmargin) from (
SELECT Date, Sum(Margin) AS Margin FROM [OpenPositions] GROUP BY Date)
Group By Datepart(week, Date)
```

Edit #2

Try This:

```
Select TBL.week, Avg(TBL.margin) from (
SELECT Datepart(week, Date) as week ,Datepart(day, Date), Sum(Margin) AS margin 
FROM [OpenPositions] GROUP BY Datepart(week, Date),Datepart(day, Date)) as TBL
Group By TBL.week
```

@calc16 in regard to your response bellow, why don't you do this:

```
Select TBL.week, Avg(TBL.margin) from 
(SELECT Datepart(week, Date) as week, Date, Sum(Margin) AS margin FROM[OpenPositions]
 GROUP BY Datepart(week, Date), Date) as TBL
Group By TBL.week
```

## Edit #4

you should add the year to the group in the inner query.

```
Select TBL.week, , Avg(TBL.margin) from 
(SELECT Datepart(week, Date) as week,Datepart(year, Date) as year, Date, Sum(Margin) AS margin FROM[OpenPositions]
 GROUP BY Datepart(week, Date), Datepart(year, Date) ,Date) as TBL
Group By TBL.week, TBL.year
```

Comment: You further need to group by on week part of date in outermost query.

Comment: the solution above will not group by week number. I need the daily sum and thereafter take the average of the daily sum (grouped by week number)

Comment: as "The Shooter" mentioned. How to implement?

Comment: Yes saw. Tried to implement, but getting NULL result on the query

Comment: @ShlomiHaver really dont understand why your solution will not work. It should work. Hmm..

Comment: @calc16 please post what this part: `SELECT Datepart(week, Date) as week ,Datepart(day, Date), Sum(Margin) AS margin 
FROM [OpenPositions] GROUP BY Datepart(week, Date),Datepart(day, Date)` returns.

Comment: @ShlomiHaver I did a modification to you code. Now it gives me the SUM on the day. SELECT Datepart(week, Date) as week, Date, Sum(Margin) AS margin FROM[OpenPositions] GROUP BY Datepart(week, Date), Date

Comment: @ShlomiHaver I tried the full code as listed above we are almost there! only thing left is to gruop by week AND year. As currert code will group the week 1's together and so forth. I tried to add Group by TBL.year, TBL.week.. but it didn't work

Comment: @ShlomiHaver FANTASTIC. You are a super star!